# onOpen function not triggered while testing primeng accordion in Angular 5

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

The onOpen function of p-accordion is not getting triggered when I test the component. open flag is set in the onOpen function and works normally but is not getting invoked when I test the component. Any idea why?

```
it('should set open to -1', fakeAsync(() => {
    const accordion = element.query(By.css('a#ui-accordiontab-0'));
    accordion.nativeElement.click();
    expect(component.open).toEqual(-1);
  }));
```

Html File

```
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="open" (onOpen)="setOpen($event)" >
            <p-accordionTab>
                ...
            </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Comment: when I try to use the document.queryselector with your `'a#ui-accordiontab-0'`. It returns undefined. I think this may be the reason. Also I have noticed you have used `#` which indicates id but used the <a> tag before that. Try to declare the id in Html for the accordion `<p-accordion [activeIndex]="open" (onOpen)="setOpen($event)" #id name >` and try to use that id in css selector.